# Sending floating point values between processes with pipes in C

Tags: c, ipc, fork

Is there a standard way of sending floating point values from a child process to a parent process in C.

I have a some calculations where I want to fork a process, then have the child do some busy work, the parent do something else, and then the child send its values (which are doubles) back to the parent (presumably through a pipe). Clearly the parent could parse the stream, but I'm just wondering if there's a cleaner way?

Comment: Define some wire protocol for the pipe, then implement it.

Comment: The only thing that could be remotely called a 'standard' way is to printf() into the pipe at one end and scanf()  at the recieving end. Either of comma delimited or newline. Doesn't really rise to the level of parsing.  Split field on delimiters and reset field count on newline.

Comment: If you're going to use text, use hex floats, not decimal. Converting them is a lot faster and you avoid all the pitfalls that could make the round-trip lossy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're just sending them between two processes on the same machine, there's no need to get fancy. On the sending side:

```
double my_float;
write(fd, &my_float, sizeof(myfloat));
```

And on the receiving side:

```
double my_float;
read(fd, &my_float, sizeof(my_float));
```

You should check the return values of `write` and `read` of course.